# How to use ColorDrawable with ImageView?

Tags: android

I have a layout with an ImageView defined like:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="45dip"
  android:layout_height="45dip"
  android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

now I just want to set the imageview to be a static color, like red or green. I'm trying:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable("FF0000");
cd.setAlpha(255);
ImageView iv = ...;
iv.setImageDrawable(cd);
```

the imageview is just empty though, no color. The 45dip space is being used up though. What do I need to do to get the color to be rendered?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looking at the constructor for ColorDrawable I don't see a version that takes a string like in your example.  I see one that takes an int.  Try this:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
```

or this for string:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"));
```

Notice I used 8 hex digits, not 6 like in your example.  This sets the alpha value as well.

**Edit:** Looking back at some of my own code where I've done something similar, I always used setBackgroundDrawable() instead of setImageDrawable() to initialize an ImageView with a solid color.  Not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: Thanks the color int I was supplying was off, I used Color.parseColor() and now it works.

Comment: if you want to use a selector with colors ( not drawables) programatically you can use : `ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFEDCACA"));`

Comment: for anyone looking how to set a solid color to a drawable (like I was), it is much easier to use imageView.setBackgroundColor()